# List conversion between different data types

Tags: java

What would be the simplest way to convert `List<Integer> to List<String>` objects. Currently I iterate through all the integers and add them to a `List<String> objects`, is there a utility function which is already available?

Comment: Any utility method would be doing the same thing. So, you are good to go with what you did. After all, its not uncommon to have a custom utility of our own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You found a simple way. The type are "incompatible", so you need a conversion rule anyway (which is simple in your case). The algorithm will always be O(n), regardless of iterating through the collections manually or calling some API method from some 3rd party library (JRE doesn't offer API for your task).

Answer (score 2):

While there are some libraries that can do general `List` transformations (like Google's [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function))) using one for this case probably won't save you any lines of code as you'd need to create a `Function` object, and that alone involves so much boilerplate that your existing code is probably smaller.

Comment: don't have a dependency on Guava, so would prefer a different package (preferably apache)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an automatic way to do this, simply because of the way Java compiles Generic arguments (called type erasure, a complicated way of saying "Haha, we're actually saving only Object references and the compiler inserts casts to the generic argument every time you do a get()" ).

Why do you have to convert it to a list of Strings? Isn't it just the same to every time you need a list of strings to just iterate through the list of Integers and call toString() on each one?

---

EDIT:

either way, here's a solution that will work:

```
public static List<String> convToString(List<Integer> list){
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Integer i : list){
        ret.add(i.toString());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And back again !

```
public static List<Integer> convToInteger(List<String> list){
    List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String s : list){
        ret.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to replace an integer within the List<Integer> with a string, which I will not be able to do until I make this conversion

Comment: Well, you could just parametrize your List to <Object> and when you need them as Strings just go through and for each element do myList.set(i, myList.get(i).toString()), but that's a really bad programming practice as it looses type safety. Why exactly do you need a List of Stings?

Comment: I perform some integer operations on the List<Integer> objects, hence I cannot declare them as an Object.

Comment: The Integer type is immutable anyway, so either way you'd have to get it from the list, cast it, unbox it, do the operation, box it, and add it back to the list, genericizing to <Integer> just makes the compiler do all of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we have a utility function for this task. Even there exist a utility function for this, it might have to iterate the `List<Integer>`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to have a List structure?  Why not do a `Map<Integer, String>`, and when an integer is inserted, a String value of that integer can be created.